# Different subclasses for same attribute

Tags: java

The example situation is as follows: I have a shop that rents items. An item (object of class Item) may be rent by PrivateCustomer or BusinessCustomer, which are both subclasses of Customer.
An item has a String name and a reference to a customer object which rents it.

My problem is: How can I make it possible that both private and businness customer are accepted? Just using the Customer superclass (Giving the Item class the attribute private Customer rentBy) didn't seem to work, it doesn't accept a PrivateCustomer in the constructor then.

I know this is a very basic question, but I'm apparently searching with the wrong keywords as I can't find an answer.

Comment: Show us your code. It should work as described

Comment: You'd have to show us your code. Generally, a constructor that accepts a superclass argument will accept actual arguments of any subclass of that superclass.

Comment: "Didn't seem to work" is very vague. Please post sample code and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your code you are not using any PrivateCustomer or BusinessCustomer attributes, just Customer.  If both Private And Business CUstomer inherit Customer, that should all work.

Sample code would help.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I used a method printDetails() which was defined in both PrivateCustomer and BusinessCustomer, but not in Customer.
Putting public void printDetails() {} into Customer solved it.

Comment: You are welcome.  Please consider accepting this answer :-).  You may also want to have your printDetails method in Customer declared abstract if it does not do anything